# Increasing the font size in XCode documentation window

Tags: xcode

I had some problems doing this but one way of doing this is listed below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XCode on the menu bar, select EDIT-> FORMAT -> FONT -> BIGGER

Comment: No effect in the current version of Xcode (at time of writing, 5.1.1).

Answer (score 8):

The given answer didn't work for me in Xcode 4.1.

However, Xcode->Preferences->Documentation->Never Use use font sizes smaller than 'x' is a workaround.

Edit: moved slightly in the newest Xcode (4.6.2). Now Xcode->Preferences->Downloads->Documentation->Never use font sizes smaller than: 'x'.

Answer (score 5):

on Xcode 4.3(still beta):
go to preferences -> downloads
choose documentation
at the bottom mark: Never use font sizes smaller than: __ (choose your size)

Answer (score 5):

Xcode menu bar，select Editor->Zoom in.

Comment: Works for Xcode 9.4.1. This would seem to be the correct answer now.